# I bought a new battery and it started for a week or 2. Now when i start it, it just clicks

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha

2005 yamaha vstar 650 classic. If I try to pop the clutch out will start but if I pop it and it doesn't start it seems like that helps because only after I do that will the start button work

Comment: Would it still be a charging issue if it starts once I try to pop the clutch? I'm probably wrong but I was guessing the stator or something that has to do with the starting cycle

Comment: If you turn on the headlights, do they seem normal brightness or a bit dim?  What's the voltage across the battery with the bike off ?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that you have a charging problem.  You put the new battery in and if it's not getting charged properly then after a while there is no longer enough power left in it to start the bike.

First of all, check all your connections.  Poor connections, especially poor GROUND connections can cause all sorts of electrical issues including charging problems.

Second, check your alternator and your voltage regulator.  Be sure you're getting the specified voltage out of the alternator when the engine is at the specified rpm.  You will likely need to refer to a service manual for this bike for the exact procedure. (A quick search of "2005 yamaha vstar 650 classic service manual" located several options for me.)